# How to add a new field to Registration form (femanager)?

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-10.x

I am using `TYPO3 10.4` with `in2code/Femanager` extension to allow front end user registration and want to add a custom field to the form.

I have followed the docs about this [here](https://docs.typo3.org/p/in2code/femanager/main/en-us/Features/NewFields/Index.html), and have my field in the form and I can save the field value if entered in the backend.

My problem is the field does not save the value when entered in the frontend form. I think I am missing something?

This is what I have:

/MyExtension/Configuration/Extbase/Persistence/Classes.php :

```
<?php

return [
    \myVendor\MyExtension\Domain\Model\User::class => [
        'tableName' => 'fe_users',
        'recordType' => 0,
    ],
];
```

/MyExtension/Configuration/PageTS/PageTSConfig.tsconfig :

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects'][\In2code\Femanager\Domain\Model\User::class] = [
    'className' => \myVendor\MyExtension\Domain\Model\User::class,
];

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\Container\Container::class)
    ->registerImplementation(
        \In2code\Femanager\Domain\Model\User::class,
        \myVendor\MyExtension\Domain\Model\User::class
    );
```

/MyExtension/Classes/Domain/Model/User.php :

```
<?php

namespace myVendor\MyExtension\Domain\Model;

use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\Category;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage;

class User extends \In2code\Femanager\Domain\Model\User
{

    protected string $myNewField;
    
    public function getMyNewField(): string
    {
        return $this->myNewField;
    }
    
    public function setMyNewField(string $myNewField): void
    {
        $this->myNewField = $myNewField;
    }

}
```

myExtension/ext_tables.sql :

```
CREATE TABLE fe_users (
    myExtension_myNewField varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
);
```

myExtension/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/fe_users.php :

```
<?php
defined('TYPO3_MODE') || die();

$GLOBALS['TCA']['fe_users']['ctrl']['type'] = 'tx_extbase_type';
$tmpFeUsersColumns = [
   'myExtension_myNewField' => [
      'exclude' => 1,
      'label' => 'My New Field',
      'config' => [
         'type' => 'text',
      ],
   ]
];

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('fe_users', $tmpFeUsersColumns);
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('fe_users', 'myExtension_myNewField');
```

myExtension/Configuration/Extbase/Persistence/Classes.php :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use myVendor\myExtension\Domain\Model\User;

return [
    User::class => [
        'tableName' => 'fe_users',
        'recordType' => 0,
    ],
];
```

myExtension/ext_localconf.php :

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['Objects'][\In2code\Femanager\Domain\Model\User::class] = [
    'className' => \myVendor\myExtension\Domain\Model\User::class,
];

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\Container\Container::class)
    ->registerImplementation(
        \In2code\Femanager\Domain\Model\User::class,
        \myVendor\myExtension\Domain\Model\User::class
    );
```

Comment: In the description you linked is written and explained: "Create ext_tables.sql and Configuration/TCA/Overrides/fe_users.php for adding one or more new fields to fe_users". Did you do that? please add your according code to your question.

Comment: small hint, `registerImplementation` should be in ext_localconf.php

Comment: @David I have now added the other files content in the question

Comment: ext_localconf.sql should include SQL but no other code. So I suppose the last codeblock in your answer is just a copy & paste fault?

Comment: For text fields the SQL definition `varchar(255)` is too short, it should be `text`.

Comment: When the field is at least be shown in the backend you can try to replace `defined('TYPO3_MODE') || die();` by `defined('TYPO3') || die();`. I'm not sure if it's working in v10, but if so then you never have to care about it in younger versions. In v12 it won't work anymore.

Comment: sorry, I had 1 wrong comment and deleted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that the field name in `ext_tables.sql` and `fe_users.php` need to be named with underscores or all lowercase eg. `my_new_field`.

And everywhere else uses camel case eg. `myNewField`.

As mentioned in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53518550/5369794)